# str_word_count() for non-latin words?

Tags: php, count

im trying to count the number of words in variable written in non-latin language (Bulgarian). But it seems that str_word_count() is not counting non-latin words. The encoding of the php file is UTF-8

```
$str = "текст на кирилица";
echo 'Number of words: '.str_word_count($str);
//this returns 0
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may do it with regex:

```
$str = "текст на кирилица";
echo 'Number of words: '.count(preg_split('/\s+/', $str));
```

here I'm defining word delimiter as space characters. If there may be something else that will be treated as word delimiter, you'll need to add it into your regex.

Also, note, that since there's no utf characters *in regex* (not in string) - `/u` modifier isn't required. But if you'll want some utf characters to act as delimiter, you'll need to add this regex modifier.

*Update*:

If you want only *cyrillic* letters to be treated in words, you may use:

```
$str = "текст 
на 12453
кирилица";
echo 'Number of words: '.count(preg_split('/[^А-Яа-яЁё]+/u', $str));
```

Comment: That is funny, I just tried this out in Ruby's `irb` to see how it acts on non-western input and also used `split` and `length` :-) Which works BTW.

Comment: Post an answer then @mvw OP can pick and choose. ;-)

Comment: well, regex is logically correct while `explode()` isn't because of possible multiple delimiters between words

Comment: Its working, but it also counts 1 letter for word, also add +1 for every new line. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Result: `Number of words: 3`

Comment: @V.Donchev so you want _only_ cyrillic letters to be words? also, multilint text works fine for me

Comment: @Fred-ii-   this example is working ,but when i tested with other variable with many words and new lines it counts: 1 letter for word, also add +1 for every new line.

Comment: You will need to show (Alma) your actual code then @V.Donchev --- Plus, Alma just did an edit, see if that works better for you.

Comment: @V.Donchev check my last update. no +1 per line is added normally in first sample. But I inverted regex - hope this will help

Comment: @Fred-ii- `str = "текст на кирилица\nfoo\nbar"` and then `str.split(/[[:space:]]/).count`, just for the record

Answer (score 1):

And here is the solution that come to my mind:

```
$var = "текст на кирилица с пет думи";
$array = explode(" ", $var);

$i = 0;
foreach($array as $item) 
    {
    if(strlen($item) > 2) $i++ ;
    }

echo $i; // will return 5
```

Answer (score 1):

As it stated in `str_word_count` [description](http://php.net/str_word_count)

> 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string

Specify Bulgarian locale before calling `str_word_count`

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'bg_BG');
echo str_word_count($content);
```

Read more about `setlocale` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

Comment: Please don't add [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685231/5292302) to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227/347985)

Comment: Excuse me, didn't know about it. Will remove my duplicate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I [found](http://blog.ozim.studio/str_word_count-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82/) is to provide a list of characters for word count function:

```php
$text = 'текст на кирилице and on english too';
$count = str_word_count($text, 0, 'АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя');
echo $count; // => 7
```

Comment: this is the best and easiest solution!