# str_word_count seems not work with Russian

Tags: php, character-encoding

I get a bad word count when I use str_word_count in Russian language. I'm configured in UTF-8 and I run php 5.5.28.

The following code returns 1:

```
echo str_word_count('Между фантазией и реальностью
Путешествие к центру Земли
СПУСК В ФУНИКУЛЕРЕ
Добрый день, уважаемые дамы и господа, добро пожаловать в Аван Арманд.
Мы находимся в этом построенном в 1963 году фуникулере, который позволит нам спуститься под землю на глубину 60 м. Фуникулер работает в туннеле длиной около 200 м, который был проложен в период 1926 - 1927 годов.
До этого доступ в пещеру был возможен по лестнице из 360 ступеней, которая находится справа от вас.');
```

The only similar thing I found is a bug report in 2008.

Is it a known problem or is there anything to configure to get it working?

I found a solution which perfectly works in all languages, on the [str_word_count documentation page](http://php.net/str_word_count#107363)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: If you don't really have a question but you just want to share some knowledge, phrase the question as an actual question, and post an answer to it.

Comment: `For the purpose of this function, 'word' is defined as a locale dependent string containing alphabetic characters, which also may contain, but not start with "'" and "-" characters.` - so what are your [locale settings](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)?

Comment: @Mark I cannot use locale I think as I provide a web page with several text areas where the user can enter a text in 'all' languages so how to do in such case?

Comment: Hey there. I removed some unnecessary text. You should definitely add the link towards the 2008 bug report and add an answer explaining what you did to solve the problem. Have a nice day!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [str\_word\_count() for non-latin words?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015600/str-word-count-for-non-latin-words)