# reading time php (little help if possible)

Tags: php, wordpress

I am in need of a little help, if it is easy to find what i am missing from my code.

I wanted a reading time calculator by minutes.

i have used the following code on my functions.php

```
function display_read_time() {
    $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
    $count_words = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
    
    $read_time = '<span class="rt-suffix">' + ceil($count_words / 250);
    
     $suffix = ' min</span>'; 
    
    $read_time_output = $read_time . $suffix;

    return $read_time_output;
}

add_shortcode( 'readingtime', 'read_time_sc' );
function read_time_sc() {
    ob_start(); ?>
            <div class="reading-time">
<?php echo display_read_time(); ?>
</div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

I inserted the function that calculates it and i made a shortcode to use it freely on my site…

I have also appended the following html on the left sidebar

```
<div class="scroll-progress-wrap">
    <div id="circ" class="p0"> 
        [readingtime]
    </div> 
</div>
```

As you will see it generates a number, but it is always 1, no matter what i do…

Do you have any idea anything i could try?

Thank you in advance!

[Link to test site](https://thefinterest.kinsta.cloud/p/uncategorized/asjalska/)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44685402/2123530?

Comment: `'<span class="rt-suffix">' + ceil($count_words / 250);` should be `'<span class="rt-suffix">' . ceil($count_words / 250);` (with a `.` instead of `+`)

Comment: thank you for the tip! that wasnt the problem unfortunately... for some reason the function doesnt count the words correctly...

Answer (score 1):

You had a `+` instead of a `.` beside your span.

In PHP concatenation is a `.`.

[Some more info on string operators for PHP.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Your code was also very messy mixing markup and code lots of pointless variables created. Keep it simple. Will be easier to spot your mistakes.

It's also better practice to put add_shortcode under the function you're creating for it as the procedure of operations is top to bottom.

```
function display_read_time() {
            $content = get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID );
            $count_words = str_word_count( strip_tags( $content ) );
        
            return '<span class="rt-suffix">' . ceil( $count_words / 250 ) . ' min</span>';
        }
        
function read_time_sc() {
            
        return '<div class="reading-time">'.display_read_time().'</div>';
            
    }
    add_shortcode( 'readingtime', 'read_time_sc' );
```

Comment: IMHO changing `display_read_time()` to `get_read_time()` and moving the `span` into `read_time_sc` would be even better

Comment: And tell that the concatenation operator is `.` and not `+` in PHP. Just in case...

Comment: @fdglefevre I don't disagree, but I don't want to assume he isn't using it elsewhere either.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help and pointers, i tried the above code and i still get 1 minute outcome on my posts, unfortunately :/ (i tried already published and creating new posts)